# Stream h264 video with opencv+gstreamer artifacts

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer

For several weeks now, I have been trying to stream h264 video over the network using opencv and gstreamer, but I am constantly confronted with problems. I wrote a simple server that captures frames from a web camera or from a file and sends it over the network. And the client who takes the video.

Server.py

```
import cv2

PIPELINE = 'appsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency speed-preset=fast ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.0.171 port=5004'
cap_send = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
frame_size = (1280, 720)
out_send = cv2.VideoWriter(PIPELINE, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER, 0, 16, frame_size, True)    

while True:
    ret, frame = cap_send.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, frame_size)
    out_send.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow('send', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break
```

Client.py

```
import cv2

PIPELINE = 'udpsrc port=5004 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! appsink'
cap_receive = cv2.VideoCapture(PIPELINE, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap_receive.read()
    cv2.imshow('receive', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break
```

As a result, I get a buggy video with artifacts. Examples [1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/129hVesstBGVJBZAaZb3KMu2Kv6YOMopI/view?usp=sharing), [2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14pubsDdNdXemaONAfRuQ5tA1cDmdVdaz/view?usp=sharing)

Also in the console I get an error:
`cv::GStreamerCapture::open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Cannot query video position: status=1, value=3, duration=-1`

What is the problem? Should I indicate some additional parameters? Or is my installation wrong?
I tried to set all kinds of parameters synk, bitrate, speed-preset, etc. but always get crippled video.

I also noticed that if you try Client.py first, then Server.py I get a normal video, which after a while will also become distorted

Answer (score 0):

Multiple things here..

1. UDP is prone to packet loss. So if either the connection is lossy or you block the receiving thread for too long you will lose data. Incomplete data means broken picture.
2. Random access. If you receive a stream while it is already running you miss data to properly decode the stream. This only will recover once you have received a sync point (I-Frame).